# Empty space in the place of icons in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, icon

I see empty spaces in Finder on OS X 10.9.4, exactly as on the picture. What does it mean? The spaces are in between the other icons, not at the end of the listing.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means there was an icon there, but it's been deleted/moved/etc and your current view doesn't do automatic sorting. Go to **View** → **Clean Up By** → **Name** to fix it just once now or press ⌘J to open View Options and set **Sort By** to **Name** to fix this now and in the future.